# Problemas en consola con el navegador

Tags: consola, navegador-web

buenas tardes cuando abro la consola del navegador para explorar mi visual studio me aparecen estos errores, desconozco que será: Estos son los errores

1. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  ((((me envia este enlace chrome-extension://gomekmidlodglbbmalcneegieacbdmki/locales/Locale-es-419.json:1)))))
2. Access to fetch at 'https://s-install.avcdn.net/aos/assets/prod/translations/Locale-es-419.json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

3.Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED  ((((me envia este enlace s-install.avcdn.net/aos/assets/prod/translations/Locale-es-419.json:1)))))

Ayuda por favor!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me paso algo parecido, concretamente con el Google Chrome, inicie deshabilitando las extensiones de Chrome, y desapareció el error, luego empecé a habilitar una a una las extensiones, y cuando habilite la extensión de Avast Online Security & Privacy, volvió el error. mi solución: deshabilitar la extensión de Avast Online Security & Privacy

Comment: Si gracias, tal cual eso hice y solucione  mi problema!